# Spring Failed to load resource when adding @GetMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Im facing an issue while Im adding a method to the controller class with when i add this @GetMapping to my controller I have a Failed to load ressource error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 () and 404()  and on the Run logs I get this message: o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : Request method 'GET' not supported

When I remove this method from the controller class, all works fine. Dont know why is this happening.

```
@GetMapping("/projet/{id}")
    public String projet(@PathVariable("id") int itemId, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("datauser", userDao.findAll());
        Project project = projectDao.findById(itemId).get();
        model.addAttribute("projet",project);
        model.addAttribute("task", new Task());
        return "projet";
    }
```

I don't understand where it comes from because before that my resources worked just fine. This is how I call it in my html :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{'/projet/'+${proj.id}}" th:object="${proj}" method="GET">
      <button><td th:text="${proj.nom}"></td></button>
</form>
```

Could you help me ? Thanks :) Eliane

Comment: try @RequestMapping(value = "/projet/{id}"). Do you have any mappings on your controller?  If so you need to append the projet url to controller url.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work...

Comment: You already have `@RequestMapping(value = "/projet/{id}")` in your controller, which by default maps to all methods. Might be causing a conflict when you add `@GetMapping("/projet/{id}")`?

Comment: It is the same I changed it after Karen's  comment

Comment: Did you check the acutal network call within the Devloper tools of your browser? Just try to click on your button and see whether or not your `${proj.id}` gets populated and added as a path variable to your call

Comment: Yes it gets populated but I get this Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 () It works form passing the info but only the css/bootstrap are not loaded So my page is ugly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way...

a)for GET methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/projet/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

b)for POST methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/projet/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```